# What is difference between size() and mappingCount() in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java

`ConcurrentHashMap` have `size()` and `mappingCount()`. It seem return the same. What is difference between them?

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Luckily, they wrote a document to explain!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ConcurrentHashMap.mappingCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#mappingCount()) returns a `long` which means it can represent more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` entries. It is also documented to be an estimate, due to the nature of concurrent access.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs at [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> ```
> public long mappingCount()
> ```
>
> Returns the number of mappings. This method should be used instead of
>   size() because a ConcurrentHashMap may contain more mappings than can
>   be represented as an int. The value returned is an estimate; the
>   actual count may differ if there are concurrent insertions or
>   removals.
>
> ```
> size()
> ```
>
> Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map.

The difference is due to the nature of concurrenthashmap and that when you call size you will obtain the size based on the current known status but the same time another thread may be changing the actual count.

Comment: Copying verbatim from the docs is a.) not a good answer and b.) problematic license-wise.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have included the source and I state from the beginning that the answer is from the official docs. Since I include the source is it still problematic license-wise?

Comment: You need to mark clearly in the answer which parts are quoted and which parts are your own text. It's ok now, remember to use quote formatting in the future.

Answer (score 0):

source code by ConcurrentHashMap
size()

```
   public int size() {
    long n = sumCount();
    return ((n < 0L) ? 0 :
            (n > (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE :
            (int)n);
}
```

mappingCount

```
public long mappingCount() {
    long n = sumCount();
    return (n < 0L) ? 0L : n; // ignore transient negative values
}
```

size return integer,mappingCount return long.
No other difference